# Как вытащить анимацию из плагина WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Для wp есть плагин называется mistape https://mistape.com. При выделении текста и нажатии Ctrl+Enter он отправляет на почту выделенный текст. Так вот там очень крутая анимация отправки письма. Пример можете посмотреть на моем сайте https://tehremzona.ru. Я хочу ее вытащить что бы использовать в других местах, но у меня не получается(( можете помочь с этим вопросом? Может ее возможно просто вызвать когда мне это нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Для overlay:

```
#mistape_dialog .dialog__overlay {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s;
}
```

На событие добавляется opacity: 1;

Для формы:

```
#mistape_dialog.dialog--open .dialog__content {
    -webkit-animation-name: anim-open;
    animation-name: anim-open;
}

#mistape_dialog.dialog--open .dialog__content, #mistape_dialog.dialog--close .dialog__content {
    -webkit-animation-duration: .3s;
    animation-duration: .3s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes anim-open {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
        transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
        transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
    }
}
```

то есть если вы хотите использовать такую анимацию то вам нужно просто для любого елемента добавить:

```
.your-class {
    -webkit-animation-duration: .3s;
    animation-duration: .3s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Если вы хотите отказаться от плагина, то не забудьте перенести @keyframes к себе в стили. И на нужное событие добавить css свойства:

```
-webkit-animation-name: anim-open;
animation-name: anim-open;
```

Comment: не срабатывает.

Comment: Поправил описание

Comment: мне кажется что мне нужна анимация send-letter которая находится в самом низу css файла. Мне нужна анимация конверта при отправке сообщения

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mistape-letter{
 width: 640px;
 height: 400px;
 top: calc(50% - 200px);
 position: absolute;
}

.mistape-letter-front{
 width: 304px;
 height: 190px;
 /*background: url(../img/letter-front.svg) no-repeat;*/
    /*background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz48IURPQ1RZUEUgc3ZnIFBVQkxJQyAiLS8vVzNDLy9EVEQgU1ZHIDEuMS8vRU4iICJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy9HcmFwaGljcy9TVkcvMS4xL0RURC9zdmcxMS5kdGQiPjxzdmcgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIiBpZD0iTGF5ZXJfMSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB4bWxuczp4bGluaz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS94bGluayIgeD0iMHB4IiB5PSIwcHgiIHdpZHRoPSI2NDBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI0MDBweCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDY0MCA0MDAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDY0MCA0MDAiIHhtbDpzcGFjZT0icHJlc2VydmUiPjxwb2x5bGluZSBpZD0ibGVmdCIgZmlsbD0iI0U1MjEyOSIgcG9pbnRzPSIwLDAgMCw0MDAgNC4wNjMsNDAwIDMyMi43NSwyMDEuNzUgMCwwICIvPjxwb2x5Z29uIGlkPSJib3R0b20iIGZpbGw9IiNENjI3MzQiIHBvaW50cz0iMCw0MDAgNjQwLDQwMCA2NDAsMzk4Ljk1MyAzMjAuMjgxLDE5OS44MjggIi8+PHBvbHlsaW5lIGlkPSJyaWdodCIgZmlsbD0iI0JDMjMzRCIgcG9pbnRzPSI2NDAsMCAzMjAsMjAwIDY0MCw0MDAgNjQwLDAgIi8+PC9zdmc+);*/
    /*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
    /*background-size: 100% 100%;*/
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 4;
 left: calc(50% - 152px);
 transform: scale(0.145);
 transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.15s;
}

.mistape-letter-front .front-left {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 152px solid #E42029;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top: 95px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 95px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.mistape-letter-front .front-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 152px solid #E42029;
    border-left: 0;
    border-top: 95px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 95px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.mistape-letter-front .front-right:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 152px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-left: 0;
    border-top: 95px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 95px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -95px;
    right: -152px;
}

.mistape-letter-front .front-bottom {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 95px solid #E42029;
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 152px solid transparent;
    border-right: 152px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.mistape-letter-front .front-bottom:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 95px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 152px solid transparent;
    border-right: 152px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -152px;
}

.mistape-letter-back{
 width: 304px;
 height: 190px;
 /*background: url(../img/letter-back.svg) no-repeat;*/
    /*background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);*/
    background-color: #E42029;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 bottom: 0;
 left: calc(50% - 152px);
 transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.15s;
 transform: scale(0.145);
 transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 opacity: 0;
}
.mistape-letter-back:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.mistape-letter-back > .mistape-letter-back-top{
 /*width: 304px;*/
 /*height: 95px;*/
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
 /*background: url(../img/letter-t2.svg) no-repeat;*/
    /*background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);*/
    border-bottom: 95px solid #E42029;
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 152px solid transparent;
    border-right: 152px solid transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 bottom: 100%;
 left: calc(50% - 152px);
 transition: transform 0.4s;
 transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 transform: translateX(0) rotateX(-180deg);
}
.mistape-letter-back > .mistape-letter-back-top:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 95px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 152px solid transparent;
    border-right: 152px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -152px;
}
.mistape-letter-top {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    /*background: url(../img/letter-t2.svg) no-repeat;*/
    /*background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);*/
    /*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
    /*background-size: 100% 100%;*/
    border-bottom: 95px solid #E42029;
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 152px solid transparent;
    border-right: 152px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 152px);
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.mistape-letter-top:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 95px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 152px solid transparent;
    border-right: 152px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -152px;
}
.mistape-letter-top.close {
 transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
#mistape_dialog .dialog__content .dialog-wrap{
 z-index: 3;
 position: relative;
}

#mistape_dialog .dialog__content.show-letter .mistape-letter-back,
#mistape_dialog .dialog__content.show-letter .mistape-letter-front{
 transform: scale(1) translateY(15%);
 opacity: 1;
}
#mistape_dialog .dialog__content.show-letter .mistape-letter-back > .mistape-letter-back-top{
 transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
#mistape_dialog .dialog__content.show-letter .dialog-wrap .dialog-wrap-top{
 transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
#mistape_dialog .dialog__content.show-letter .dialog-wrap .dialog-wrap-bottom{
 background: #c1c1c1;
}
#mistape_dialog .dialog__content.show-letter .dialog-wrap .dialog-wrap-bottom textarea{
 background: #c1c1c1;
}
#mistape_dialog .dialog__content.show-letter .dialog-wrap{
 transform: translateY(-150%);
}
#mistape_dialog .dialog__content.show-letter.with-comment .dialog-wrap{
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#mistape_dialog .mistape_action[data-action="send"]{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 8;
}
#mistape_dialog .dialog__content.show-letter .mistape_action[data-action="send"]{
 transition-delay: 0.3s;
 transition: visibility 0.1s, opacity 0.1s;
 visibility: hidden!important;
 opacity: 0!important;
}


@keyframes send-letter1 {
 0% { transform: translateX(0) translateY(15%); }
 20% { transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(15%); }
 100% { transform: translateX(100vw) translateY(15%); }
}

@-moz-keyframes send-letter1 {
 0% { transform: translateX(0) translateY(15%); }
 20% { transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(15%); }
 100% { transform: translateX(100vw) translateY(15%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes send-letter1 {
 0% { transform: translateX(0) translateY(15%); }
 20% { transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(15%); }
 100% { transform: translateX(100vw) translateY(15%); }
}

@keyframes send-letter2 {
 0% { transform: translateX(0) rotateX(-180deg); }
 20% { transform: translateX(-60%) rotateX(-180deg); }
 100% { transform: translateX(100vw) rotateX(-180deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes send-letter2 {
 0% { transform: translateX(0) rotateX(-180deg); }
 20% { transform: translateX(-60%) rotateX(-180deg); }
 100% { transform: translateX(100vw) rotateX(-180deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes send-letter2 {
 0% { transform: translateX(0) rotateX(-180deg); }
 20% { transform: translateX(-60%) rotateX(-180deg); }
 100% { transform: translateX(100vw) rotateX(-180deg); }
}
```